# Bootstrap 4 responsive vertical nav bar height large space

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a responsive vertical nav bar using bootstrap. I have the issue where when on my desktop it works as expected (nav bar 100% height down the left side) but on mobile there is a significant space that i cannot remove.

I've circled the area i want to remove below
[image]

```
        <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
          <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col-md-auto pr-md-0 bg-light">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light flex-row flex-md-column align-items-start px-0">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                  <img src="/static/img/logo.png">
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-toggler" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
                  <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    Projects etc, make this vertical
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
          <div class="col pt-md-3" id="applicationContentContainer"></div>
        </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's because of the `h-100`

Comment: how do i preserve the h-100 on my desktop but remove it on mobile?

Comment: Do you have other CSS? please post it. Also clarify what you're trying to do? Is the navbar full width on mobile or is it vertical sidebar? How is it suppoesed to look on desktop?

Comment: There is no other CSS. On mobile it is full width with clickable dropdown. On desktop it's meant to be vertical sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using h-100 which forces the row to be 100% height, use `min-vh-100` and the responsive flexbox direction classes `flex-column flex-md-row`...

https://codeply.com/p/9OU846ri1A

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row min-vh-100 flex-column flex-md-row">
        <div class="col-md-2 pr-md-0 bg-light">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light flex-row flex-md-column align-items-start px-0">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img src="//placehold.it/30">
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-toggler" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-md-n2" id="navbarToggle">
                    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-column">
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                        <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col pt-md-3" id="applicationContentContainer">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries and replace h-100 in html with any of following class according to your device needs so that it will be applied only starting from particular device:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {

  .h-sm-100 {
    height: 100% !important;
  }
 .h-sm-auto {
    height: auto !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .h-md-100 {
    height: 100% !important;
  }
  .h-md-auto {
    height: auto !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .h-lg-100 {
    height: 100% !important;
  }
  .h-lg-auto {
    height: auto !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

  .h-xl-100 {
    height: 100% !important;
  }
  .h-xl-auto {
    height: auto !important;
  }
}
```